# How can I draw a digital interactive indoor map for a building?

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend, maps, autocad

My graduation project requires drawing couple of indoor maps. Maps will be drawn for the administrator using web technologies and on a mobile phone for the users. 
 How can I draw maps using front end web technologies, and if I have CAD file for the building I'm drawing, can I somehow convert the CAD file to an interactive digital map?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would likely be to use SVG. You should be able to export your CAD directly to SVG, but if not, one way would be to export it as PDF, open it in Inkscape and save as SVG.

Take the resultant SVG and paste it into the body of your html.

Then, you can use Javascript and CSS to add interactivity to the SVG.

This is good for a one time conversion: if you want to make updates to the CAD and have them update automatically you would have to script it or use software designed to publish to the web (which will vary depending on what CAD system you are using).